# Как в GoLang проверить содержит ли массив значение?

Tags: массивы, golang

Изучаю GoLang, стало интересно как проверить есть ли значение в массиве.

Есть функция `strings.Contains`, но она проверяет есть ли строка в строке, не массив.

Есть ли функция для этого, или надо писать свою?

Comment: Вопрос именно про массив? Или же имеется в виду map?

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko именно про массив, (например `[3]int{1, 2, 3}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В модуле [`slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices) есть функция [`Contains`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains):

```go
found := slices.Contains(some_slice, some_value))
```

`found` будет `true` если `some_value` есть в `some_slice`, иначе `false`.

UPD: В GoLang 1.21 модуль `slices` стал встроенным.

Answer (score 1):

Если массив не отсортирован, то есть функция [slices.IndexFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#IndexFunc)

```
// искать индекс элемента target
idx := slices.IndexFunc(someSlice, func (elt E) { return elt == target })
if idx >= 0 { /* найден */ }
```

Но это реально тривиальная функция:

```
func IndexFunc[E any](s []E, f func(E) bool) int {
    for i := range s {
        if f(s[i]) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Если же массив отсортирован, то есть функция поиска делением пополам [`slices.BinarySearch`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#BinarySearch) - ищет для типов, для которых определено сравнение `<`. В общем случае есть поиск по отсортированному слайсу с компаратором [`slices.BinarySearchFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#BinarySearchFunc)

Comment: Я приму свой ответ, про slices.Contains, потому что он больше подходит к вопросу, но думаю это не страшно, у вас есть мой за.